# problems with ng update

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase

Iam trying to run 
**ng update**
 on my mac, but I am getting an error, the same when I try to run **npm install** on a cloned git project.

Anybody can help me? (log file below)

```
`
7826 warn @angular/fire@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
7827 warn @angular/fire@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
7828 warn @angular/fire@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
7829 warn @angular/fire@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
7830 verbose stack Error: puppeteer@1.9.0 install: `node install.js`
7830 verbose stack Exit status 1
7830 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
7830 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
7830 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
7830 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
7830 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
7830 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
7830 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
7830 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
7831 verbose pkgid puppeteer@1.9.0
7832 verbose cwd /Users/khaelbubniak/DEV/dragdrop/dragdrop/dragdrop
7833 verbose Darwin 17.4.0
7834 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--quiet"
7835 verbose node v8.12.0
7836 verbose npm  v6.4.1
7837 error code ELIFECYCLE
7838 error errno 1
7839 error puppeteer@1.9.0 install: `node install.js`
7839 error Exit status 1
7840 error Failed at the puppeteer@1.9.0 install script.
7840 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
7841 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
`
```

Comment: Check the version of node and npm. This can give some issues also

Comment: I checked everything, but i've found in a thread in github that the problem may be that I need to use Sudo on every npm command

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are running the npm install or ng update from the same folder location where you have your package.json file.